# The current path, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

So I have code below that is in django 1.8

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from account import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='profile'),
    url(r'^api/get_users/(?P<term>.*)', views.get_users),
    url(r'^leaderboard/(?P<board_type>.*)', views.leaderboard),
    url(r'^admintools/(?P<action>.*)', views.admintools),
)
```

I modified it to django 2.2

```
from django.conf.urls import  url
from . import views
from django.urls import re_path,path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='profile'),
    path('api/get_users/(?P<term>.*)', views.get_users),
    path('leaderboard/(?P<board_type>.*)', views.leaderboard),
    path('admintools/(?P<action>.*)', views.admintools),
]
```

I get the error The current path account/admintools, didn't match any of these

Comment: Seems you are not providing any `<action>` to the url. `admintools/<action>` will match the fourth url. or at least `admintools/`

Comment: You still have some regex syntax there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"one of the easy solutions"* to this problem is, use [**`re_path(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path) instead of **`path()`**

```
from django.urls import re_path
from account import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.index, name='profile'),
    re_path(r'^api/get_users/(?P<term>.*)', views.get_users),
    re_path(r'^leaderboard/(?P<board_type>.*)', views.leaderboard),
    re_path(r'^admintools/(?P<action>.*)', views.admintools),
]
```

The **`re_path(...)`** function will do ***the same thing*** as the [Django **`url(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#url)  did.